# Python+selenium+firefox NTLM authentication with pop(alert) window issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've already tried three ways, and only the first way can work.

1. Add user information in front of url, and this is the only way success.

   url_address = "http://username:passwd@abc.cde.com/"
   browser = webdriver.Firefox()
   browser.get(url_address)

2.Second way is use .switch_to_alert() to switch to pop window
  and use send_keys() to key in user information, it work just fine until send_key(Keys.TAB) have used; It will TAB the input maker into password field but when send_key("password") line, **It jumps back to username field** and then key in password! I have make a Demo gif link below.
[image: Demo with Key.TAB]

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url_address)
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.alert_is_present(),"wait for alert pop out")
alert_window=browser.switch_to_alert()
alert_window.send_keys("username")
time.sleep(5)
alert_window.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(5)
alert_windows.send_keys("passwd")
```

time.sleep is in order to know if TAB really work or not.
Same result if it removed

> Update 11/14 change send_keys to one line and it work as expect
>   Like this alert_window.send_keys("username"+Keys.TAB+"passwd")

3.Third way is use alert_window.authenticate()but it return

*selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/c7411dfa-5a0e-41e3-b8b3-e8f7d9dc9843/alert/credentials did not match a known command*

Any idea to fix issue on 2 and 3 ?
tool list :
python 3.6.2
selenium
firefox 54.0.1 (32 bit)

Comment: Could you share a part of your html code? To see what kind of pop-up is (an alert with fields, a small window, etc). Thank you.

Comment: @j.barrio The pop-up is't generate by html , it is use to certificate if Windows account is in Domain ,and every browser will looks different.
here is firefox and microsoft edge
edge : [link](https://imgur.com/WuE6gYi)
Firefox:[link](https://imgur.com/2bymljs)
Thanks your help !

Comment: With the image only I can't help you to much. With the demo, maybe you could create a unique send_keys action with "username" + Keys.TAB + "passwd" to see what happens.

Comment: @j.barrio Thanks you sir ! It work after I change send_keys to 
send_keys(username+Keys.TAB+passwd)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks! The Udate on 11/14 works for me too.